# `for` loop in discord.py does not execute if...elif statements sequentially

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

As the title states, I created a simple bot using discord.py that responds to a list of commands as such (the code has been truncated for brevity):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@bot.command()
async def respond_to_me(ctx):

    my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

    for item in my_list:
        if item == 1: await ctx.send("You said one")
        elif item == 2: await ctx.send("You said two")
        elif item == 3: await ctx.send("You said three")
        elif item == 4: await ctx.send("You said four")
        else: pass

bot.run(bot_token)
```

However, executing code with `my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]` sometimes returns the following response (which changes randomly with repeated execution):

```
"You said one"
"You said three"
"You said two"
"You said four"
```

What is happening? I don't understand how simple code can return different results with each execution? What do I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Because *that's what asynchronous means*.

Comment: Remove await so it's not async.

Comment: But removing await gives the following error: “the process was not awaited”

Comment: @MadisonCourto Removing await will give an error.

Comment: please refer to [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

Answer (score 1):

A rough solution could be to `asyncio.sleep()` (will need to `import asyncio`) for a little bit after each iteration, so each request has time to be processed in the correct order.